# Can I create automatic headings in a Microsoft Word document which has around 500 pages?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to add headings automatically in a Word document which has 500 pages. All the topics written with the font 'Courier' and Size '24' needs to be given style - 'Heading 1'. Can someone help me write this using VBA?

Comment: Why would you need VBA to create a header on your pages? That's built in to Word.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this using VBA?

The Advanced Find function let's you highlight all text in your document based on parameters like font and size.

Set these parameters using the "Format"-dropdown -> "Font..."
Then use the "Find In"-dropdown -> "Main Document" to select all text matching your criteria.

See attached screenshot, and then manually set the style for the entire highlighted selection.

[image: Advanced Find to highlight text]